# Google Drive OSX app automatically upload files from various root folders

Tags: google-apps, file-sharing, macos

I'm trying to sync folders from my computer to Google Drive using the OSX app, but the folders aren't in the "Google Drive" folder.

I made a symlink in the "Google Drive" folder to the folder that needs to be synced, and the symlink works correctly, but for some reason the app is choosing to completely ignore the symlink folder. For example, everything else that's in the "Google Drive" folder has the check-mark next to it meaning its synced, but any folder thats a symlink seems completely invisible to the Drive OSX app.

After I thought this solution would work, I found this, which says to do the same thing, but for some reason it's not working:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50754/google-drive-share-a-folder-which-is-not-in-the-root

Yes, the symlink works like normal, and I'm comfortable with terminal, and I've made symlinks plenty of times in the past (For purposes other than Google Drive) and have never had a problem.

Also, I'm not stuck on the symlink solution... any solution will work.

Comment: Since you're asking about the file sync feature and not the web interface, your question is better suited to [su].